# How do fundamentally electrostatic lenses work?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, lenses

I don't need any super specific answers. But I would it appreciate alot if someone could either confirm or correct my thought process.

I know that for many of you this will sound super obvious but for me this is new knowledge.

So electrostatics usually implies that electric charges are **not moving**.

In the case of a lense I imagine it to be like a ring, that somehow gets charged with either positive or (usually) negative charges.

These charges are not moving (or at least not significantly) but they still create an electrical field around them. And this field then acts like a lense (kind of, I know that this is a bit more complicated) on incoming charges that go through that ring.

Is that thought process correct so far? Would the fact that charges are not moving imply that there is little to no voltage present?

Bonus question:
Again this might be trivial to alot of you guys, but how would one go about charging such a ring up? How does one pump electrical charges into such a ring that are supposed to not move?

Comment: Are you asking about electron lenses or optical lenses?

Comment: The (moving) electron goes through a region with a fixed, static electric field. Different incident positions/angles of the moving electrons see different fields, getting steered so they are focused (or unfocused).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that thought process correct so far?

Yes.

> Would the fact that charges are not moving imply that there is little to no voltage present?

No. Whether or not the charges are fixed, there is an $E$-field, and thus the voltage between two arbitrarily chosen points $x_1$ and $x_2$ inside the field is given by:

$$\Delta V_{12}=V_{x_2}-V_{x_1}=-\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \hat{E}d\hat{l}\space.$$

The voltage increase from point $1$ to point $2$ is equal to the work done per unit charge, against the electric field, to move the charge from $1$ to $2$ uniformly. For instance, whether or not a parallel plate capacitor is made of nonconductive or conductive plates, the voltage between the charged plates is $V=Ed$, where $d$ is the distance between the plates. Remember that a zero electric current does not necessarily imply a zero voltage but the vice versa is always true, i.e., a zero voltage implies a zero current between the points that the voltage is attributed.

In electrostatic lensing, the external electric field of the static charges located inside the rings produces nonzero voltages for the beam of moving electrons and changes the direction and possibly the magnitude of the initial *current* that can be attributed to the beam.

Comment: Ah, that is very interesting.

So first you are saying that there can/is voltage present regardless of whether the charges in the ring are moving or not.

This might sound stupid, but I am used to think of voltage in terms of electrical circuits as a 'pushing force' coming from a battery for example.
So when you now say there is voltage present are you referring to the charges INSIDE the ring or do you mean that the electrons in the beam which is going through the ring are feeling a non-zero voltage?

Comment: Second, assuming that you were referring to the electrons that go through that ring, I still would like to know what kind of voltage/current are present INSIDE such a ring. I mean for me as an engineer I'd like to know whether it is safe or super dangerous. 

That's also why I asked HOW one would go about charging such a ring with charges that then create the E-field.

Comment: @CatoMaths - remember, a capacitor when charged has a static electric field between the plates and no current flowing. An electrostatic lens is pretty much a capacitor, with different bits at different voltages to create a static electric field that the electron/ion beam can propagate through. This static field alters the trajectories of the charged particles such that a lens effect is created.

Comment: @CatoMaths *So when you now say there is voltage present are you referring to the charges INSIDE the ring or do you mean that the electrons in the beam which is going through the ring are feeling a non-zero voltage?* The electrons in the beam, I meant.

Comment: @CatoMaths *I still would like to know what kind of voltage/current are present INSIDE such a ring* It depends on whether the ring is made of a conductive or non-conductive material. If it is conductive, the $E$-field is zero everywhere inside the ring, and thus the voltage is zero for any two arbitrary points inside the ring. However, the $E$-field of the *beam* can trifilingly affect the charge distribution inside the rings as it passes close to the ring, and thus, due to some small voltages, there appear some small currents inside the rings. ...

Comment: ... On the other hand, if the rings are nonconductive, the charge distribution inside the rings is often in a way that, between any two arbitrary points, there is an $E$-field (voltage), however, these fields (voltages) cannot produce currents at all because the charges are fixed.

Comment: Ohh ok! That makes sense! 

So I'll quickly repeat what I just learned.

1.Once the Electrostatic lense is turned on (charged up) it will always generate an E-Field/Voltage for the electron beam going through that ring. This then can be used to alter the path or energy of the electron beam going through.

Comment: 2. Depending on the material there can be either no E-field inside the ring, or there can be but either way, there is NO movement of charges inside the ring.

Comment: 3. Finally the E-field created by the electron beam, could potentially have a minor effect on the charges in the ring.

Comment: Ok last question:
What role does 'leakage current' play in this context? I heard the word popping up in the lecture and I have no idea what it has to do with the set-up as a whole. I don't even know whether the leakage current is something desired or not.